# Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.7.0

Tags: npm, platform

I am trying to run contentful-starter applation using "npm run dev" command. I am getting the below error. I am littlebit new to npm . Kindly help me, it would be great if you can suggest any solution. Thank you

These are the commands I executed before running "npm run dev"

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
gatsby new contentful-starter https://github.com/contentful/starter-gatsby-blog
cd contentful-starter
npm run setup
npm run dev
```

```
Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=node abi=108 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.7.0
loaded from: D:\contentful\contentful-starter\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\lmdb

at Function.load.path (D:\contentful\contentful-starter\node_modules\node-gyp-build\index.js:60:9)
at load (D:\contentful\contentful-starter\node_modules\node-gyp-build\index.js:22:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\contentful\contentful-starter\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\lmdb\node-index.js:17:45)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\contentful\contentful-starter\node_modules\gatsby\src\util
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that binary for your environment is missing in lmdb-store. Try it with Node version 17. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to bring up my environment and suddenly received a network error while the first npm i was going on.

Quick solution, go to the node_modules folder, and wipe it all. Then run `npm i` again, most likely it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should check to make sure your binaries have been properly installed by NPM first, your binary should be at `D:\contentful\contentful-starter\node_modules\gatsby\node_modules\lmdb\lmdb-win32-x64`, if not, you can install by `npm install @lmdb/lmdb-win32-x64`